# Mount Myoboku: a different space/dimension?

Tags: naruto

There are two ways to enter mount Myōboku:

1. A secret path from Konohagakure
2. Reverse summoning

So there is no way (as known so far) that you are traveling somewhere and by mistake end up landing on mount Myōboku. Neither is it shown on any map in any episode.

I assumed that it's a different space or world. (Than the shinobi's)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So there is no way (as known so far) that you are traveling somewhere and by mistake end up landing on mount Myōboku.

According to the [Official Character Databook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Naruto-Official-Character-Data-Book/dp/1421541254/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1363006529&sr=1-1) that is not the case, as the book states that:

> (...) it is said that once in a while, a traveler who has lost his way inadvertently gets on the secret path.<sup>1</sup>

However, even this neither proves nor disproves that it is located in our world. One could get lost and get in some secret path that leads to a region in this world, but getting lost may, just as well, lead you to some secret path that transports you to another dimension.
However, I think it is located in our world, because "Secluded Region" appears written in the page that has info on Mount Myōboku. This piece of info leads me to think that Mount Myōboku is just located in some region that is very well hidden from the outside world. However, it may just as well mean that the "Secluded Region" is some other dimension.

[image: Page from Official Character Databook]

So, basically, it is unknown whether it is located in our world or in another, at least as of now (chapter 623).

---

<sup>1</sup> Page 204, *Naruto: The Official Character Data Book*

Comment: just wondering, if Naruto never returned from the mt myoboku (just a thought) .. Could Pain or anyone reach him by force?? What's your thought?

Comment: I'm thinking that *theoretically* it would be possible. Provided that either they *knew* the way there, or that they got lucky enough to *get lost* and find their way there.

Comment: So the same goes with the *Ryūchi Cave* and *Shikkotsu Forest*?

Comment: @R.J Possibly, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku):

> For a human to get to Mount Myōboku, it either takes a month long travel on secret paths from Konohagakure or, if they have a summoning contract, they can let a toad use the Reverse Summoning Technique. According to Fukasaku, Mount Myōboku is impossible to find by foot for those who don't know the secret route. (Chapter 409)

But whether or not it is in another dimension is nowhere stated. Additionally it is not shown on the [World map](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aNaruto_World_Map.svg) of Naruto. So it could be on an unknown place on this world (as on an island not yet discovered by the shin-obis or as you said in another dimension or even on another planet.

Comment: Yes, I share the same assumption. Thank you.